# Error while invoking COM+ component with MSMQ Triggers

Tags: msmq, com+

I am trying to invoke a COM+ method while a MSMQ message is inserted into queue using MSMQ triggers. While trying to invoke I get the below error

```
The action defined by the rule # with the ID 냈# was not invoked. The COM object may not be registered, or the executable file may not exist in your path. Error 0xc00e0e0a
```

The below is my class library

```
[Guid("D924540B-BAC7-4764-9250-8494D497A079"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(DBCOM_Events))]
public class MyComLibClass : myinterface
{
    public void sayLibHello()
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("d:/sam.txt", "hi from component : " + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

[Guid("EA3F8BB3-3670-4C86-9456-6B913DEF9AFF")]
public interface myinterface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void sayLibHello();
}

[Guid("AF9D6B2D-566D-4314-9B62-EBD14C10C4E8"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface DBCOM_Events
{
}
```

And the assembly info is

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

I have added the Strong Name using a file and added it through project properties and also enabled

[image]

For registering the dll I used the below commands

```
regasm ClassLibrary1.dll /tlb:ClassLibrary1.tlb
```

and

```
gacutil /i ClassLibrary1.dll
```

I created a COM+ application using

```
comexp.msc
```

I installed both the TypeLibrary and Imported the registered component using the "Com+ Install Component wizard".

And in case Of MSMQ, \

```
1 . Created a MSMQ
2 . Gave full control to 'Everyone'
3 . Created a Trigger for that Queue
4 . Created rule with some simple condition like, the label does not contain 'xyz'.
5 . Selected Invoke Com+ component and specified the class name and method name.
6 . Both MessageQueue service and MessageQueueTrigger service is running.
```

I don't know what I am missing. I searched in net but couldn't resolve this issue. Please help me on this. I am stuck with this issue from the last week.

Thanks
Jonathon

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm getting a similar error for my trigger under Windows 8.1, however the same trigger installs correctly under Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to post this as a comment, but haven't got enough reputation yet.

This is a long shot, but I found a similar error report from years ago where they advised to run FileMon.exe to check if the referenced file is missing or not in path. Filemon should be able to help you locate the call for this missing / failing file.

Also is the UniCode in the error (냈#) deliberate or part of the reason it does not work?

Comment: The assembly is definately in the GAC as I can call the COM+ module from a test executable I wrote and get the expected result,  but I will try filemon tomorrow to see if it reveals anything new.  The unicode error is not deliberate and I can't explain it.

Comment: Curious. I ran _Procmon_ as I was restarting the _MSMQ Trigger Service_ after reinstalling the COM+ component. There is a procmon that has the path `C:\Development\MyApp\net.*` (the folder containing the DLL) and the result `NO SUCH FILE`.  As before, I can see the expected test output when I execute the COM+ module using a test executable with an `InvokeMember` method call like so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1511/Accessing-COM-component-using-C. I'll comment here once I figure it out.

Comment: The command which ran the `net.*` query was `VsDevCmd.bat` (the Visual Studio command line I'm using to run `regsvcs`) so I think that error is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I noticed that the same error was occurring for Windows Server 2008 R2 when I tried a new method. I had previously thought that is was only occurring for Windows 8.1. After some trial and error I realized that it had to do with the trigger properties. To replicate:

1. I had the trigger Rule setup to include the Properties *Message ID (as variant)* and *Message body (as variant)*
2. the signature of
   the COM+ method was:

   ```
           public string MyComMethod(string queueMessageId, object messageBody)
   ```

Note that the *Message ID (as variant)* property is a `variant` not a string - this seems to be the underlying issue, i.e. the interface doesn't match what is being passed in via the trigger.

Once I removed the `string queueMessageId` from the message signature and from the trigger properties, the triggers began to run for both Windows Server 2008 RS SP1 and Windows 8.1. If you need to receive the *Message ID (as variant)* on your COM+ interface, the correct parameter type is `byte[]`. This must be converted back to a `string` in order for it to be used with `ReceiveById` and other methods - see http://goo.gl/91Pp6R and http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.cx/2003-11/msg00035.html

My convert method for MessageIDs is a bit ad-hoc, but it appears to work:

```
private static string ConvertId(byte[] queueMessageId)
{
    var guidAsByteArray = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(queueMessageId, guidAsByteArray, 16);

    //Start at position 16 to get the unique message ID
    return String.Format(
        @"{0}\{1}", 
        new Guid(guidAsByteArray), 
        BitConverter.ToUInt32(queueMessageId, 16)
    );
}
```

Regarding the cryptic characters in the error, I suspect that the COM+ error logging is struggling with the MSIL DLL, but it isn't stopping the trigger from running so it's tolerable. I will post here if I figure this out.